# Singly linked list - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type

Tags: java, linked-list, generic-list, type-erasure

I am working a singly linked list to learn Java.

I have a working linked list but it binds to integer type, now I am trying to implement a generic typed linked list by changing all the integer declaration to generic type E.

The compiler keeps complaining that it "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E". The code still runs. Does anybody know how to fix this error " ?

I think it has something to do with whether the generic type E is static like integer or double or if it is a reference type like String or other classes.

```
public class TestingLinkedList<E> {


private E value;
private TestingLinkedList<E> next;

/*
 * Default Constructor
 * 
 * @param value an absolute E value for the current Node
 * 
 * @param next an absolute RecursiveLinkedList value for the current Node
 */
public TestingLinkedList(E value, TestingLinkedList next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

/*
 * Constructor Empty, when user supplies an empty for the constructor uses
 * value = - 1 and next = null as input parameters
 * 
 * @param value an absolute int value for the current Node
 * @param next an absolute RecursiveLinkedList value for the current Node
 */
public static final TestingLinkedList EMPTY = new TestingLinkedList(null,null) 
{
    public TestingLinkedList remove(E n) {
        return this;
    };

    public String toString() {
        return "";
    };
};

/*
 * if the current node is null return false
 * else if current value is the chosen value
 * then return true. Otherwise call the contains
 * method of the next item in queue
 * 
 * @param value an absolute int value for the current Node
 * @param RecursiveLinkedList object of the remove item
 * */
public TestingLinkedList remove(E n) {
    if (value == n) {
        return next;
    }
    // Call the remove method of the next Node if the selected Node is not
    // the current node then construct and return the next method
    return new TestingLinkedList(value, next.remove(n));
}

/*
 * if the current node is null return false
 * else if current value is the chosen value
 * then return true. Otherwise call the contains
 * method of the next item in queue
 * 
 * @param value an absolute int value for the current Node
 * @param boolean
 * */
public boolean contains(E n) {
    if (next == null) {
        return false;
    }else if (value == n) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return next.contains(n);
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return value + "," + next.toString();
}


/*
 * 
 * Testing Methods for RecursiveLinkedList
 * 
 * */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestingLinkedList l = new TestingLinkedList(1,
            new TestingLinkedList(2, new TestingLinkedList(2,
                    new TestingLinkedList(3, new TestingLinkedList(4,
                            EMPTY)))));
    System.out.println(" Test to String Method : " + l.toString());
    System.out.println(" Test remove method " + l.remove(1).toString());
    System.out.println(" Test contains method "
            + String.valueOf(l.contains(4)));
}
```

}

Comment: The block `if (value == n) {...}` is suspicious too.  That should probably be an `Object.equals()` call.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final TestingLinkedList EMPTY = new TestingLinkedList(null,null)
```

Should be:

```
public static final TestingLinkedList<Integer> EMPTY
                                      = new TestingLinkedList<Integer>(null,null)
```

This violates the generics, since the placeholder for `E` is determined at construction time, and this is static, it can't use the `E` value. Instead use the *generic method*:

```
public static <T> TestingLinkedList<T> empty() {
    return new TestingLinkedList<T>(null, null) {

        public TestingLinkedList remove(T n) {
            return this;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I have doubt about the way how you implement the "Empty". I could be wrong, but the compiler is still complaining.

Comment: Oh, sorry. This should help, see Edit.